# Investigate an elasticsearch becoming slow 3h a day outside business hours

Tags: elasticsearch

The latency for all elastic search operations goes from 0.1s to 2s.
This is happening during 2 or 3 hours outside of our business hours.
The business hours take 100rpm, outside business hours take 25rpm.
It happened the last 3 days.

Many metrics correlate with the latency peak:

- latency (0.1s → 2s)
- CPU (30% → 90%)
- memory is stable (1.3G used / 1.8G total)
- merge duration (400 → 7k)
- breaker size (50k → 500k)
- index refresh duration (500 → 6k)
- management threads (1 → 130)
- opened HTTP connections (260 -> 400)
- pending tasks (0.07 -> 1)

My unexperimented opinion is ES is performing index merge/refresh when activity is low because it's impossible during the day. Also, when index merge/refresh is made, everything is slow and more HTTP connections are opened.

Does Elastic have such behavior to perform management tasks when it's less busy?
What other values should be watched to understand the situation / fix it?

Comment: Nothing to help, any documentation or experiment about having long latency after the workload ? Best